# Changing OpenCV Contour Tolerance

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image that I've for the most part isolated all the information I'd like to work with in. In the image I have several "circles" that I want the contour function to be able to identify. Currently it's settings don't identify them and instead focus on singular pixels in the image.

Link to isolated image (can't embed images yet) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmXGK.jpg

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(opening.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

This is the code I've got to actually identify the contours in the image and it works in a similar image with larger "circles".

I'd like for the image to have circles drawn over the isolated circle areas but I first need to ID them. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that through the OpenCV documentation and was hopeful someone can help/give advice, thanks!

--Edit
This is my pre-processing code

```
height, width, depth = image.shape
newimg = cv2.resize(image,(int(width/2.5),int(height/2.5)))
img_thresholded = cv2.inRange(newimg, (86, 31, 4), (220, 88, 50))
kernel = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img_thresholded, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
```

Comment: you should mask the image before 'findContours'

Comment: I'm changing the image value to just contain the relevant pixels if that's what you mean, I'll edit the original question to contain my pre-processing code

Comment: might you provide the original image before and after processing ?

Comment: There are plenty of examples if you just search this forum. For example, see the answer by nathancy at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57297612/measuring-the-diameter-pictures-of-holes-in-metal-parts-photographed-with-telec/57300051#57300051. That should give you an example to study.

Comment: That's a very interesting thread, I'm looking over it closely, thank you!

Comment: @Zhubei-Federer I am not allowed to post the original image, sorry

Comment: @fmw42 Do you think that inverting the current color scheme and the running the dilate mask over it would be a good idea?

Comment: Okay so I was able to clean up the image a bit more so now it's much less noisy and looks like this --> https://imgur.com/a/T9Un9IR. I can still not detect any circles at all

Comment: How do you know you have no contours? Have you drawn them onto your image? Perhaps you need to show the whole code and not just snippets.

Comment: I’ve drawn contours onto the image using the regular tutorial method, all the contours that cv2.findContours returns are located in the upper left corner and are about 10-45pixels in size, it doesn’t draw any on the holes it should.