# Measuring the size of bubbles from a picture of material particles - Python-OPenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to measure the size and count of bubbles available in image taken from real world material particles.

I have tried the approach present [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57297612/measuring-the-diameter-pictures-of-holes-in-metal-parts-photographed-with-telec) (second one with opencv). But some how it doesnt work probably because of the bubbles, because image is kind of an average quality.

Can some one please direct me to correct direction or provide recommendation?

The reference image, i am trying process is

[image: below]

Result:
It doesn't detects the circles, in fact at finding contours step, it gets a zero therefore the test is not passed.

**Made some changes. Able to detect some bubbles but still not good. Detected bubble image is below**

[image: after processing]

Thanks

**Code:**

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('....')

# Gray, blur, adaptive threshold
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Morphological transformations
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    # Find perimeter of contour
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    # Perform contour approximation
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * perimeter, True)
    if len(approx) > 6:

            # Obtain bounding rectangle to get measurements
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

            # Find measurements
            diameter = w
            radius = w/2

            # Find centroid
            M = cv2.moments(c)
            cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
            cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

            # Draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
            cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),4)
            cv2.drawContours(image,[c], 0, (36,255,12), 4)
            cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 15, (320, 159, 22), -1)

            # Draw line and diameter information
            cv2.line(image, (x, y + int(h/2)), (x + w, y + int(h/2)), (156, 188, 24), 3)
            cv2.putText(image, "Diameter: {}".format(diameter), (cX - 50, cY - 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 3, (156, 188, 24), 3)
cv2.imwrite('...', image)
cv2.imwrite('...', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('...', opening)
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample picture and a picture showing the result of the approach you linked to ?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to add it. I added now.

Comment: If you have time to explore this and deep learning is a possibility (they have many downsides, especially for the industry that is looking for explainable results), I would advise you to try deep learning, for instance the Unet network.

Comment: Thank you @GabrielDevillers
I  will try that. Thanks for recomendation

Comment: Also, could you use stackoverflow's image service to insert your image ? That will prevent the google drive link from breaking one day. If you have not enough reputation points, I can do it for you.